# ProgressDialog not appearing

Tags: java, android, progressdialog

I have code that starts a `ProgressDialog` inside an `AsyncTask`, it looks like this:

```
class RetrieveApps extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<ApplicationInfo>> {
    PackageManager pm;

    @Override
    protected List<ApplicationInfo> doInBackground(String...params) {
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Apps.this,
                "Retreiving Application list",
                "Retrieving list of installed applications", true);
        pm = getPackageManager();
        return pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<ApplicationInfo> result) {
        for(ApplicationInfo nfo : result){
            Drawable icon = nfo.loadIcon(pm);
            String name = nfo.loadLabel(pm).toString();
            if(name != null && icon != null){
                apps.add(new App(name, icon));
            }
        }
        dialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

I'm getting a `RuntimeException` saying

> Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

It points at the line where `ProgressDialog.show()` was called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class RetrieveApps extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<ApplicationInfo>> {
    PackageManager pm;

    @Override
    protected List<ApplicationInfo> doInBackground(String...params) {

        pm = getPackageManager();
        return pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<ApplicationInfo> result) {
        for(ApplicationInfo nfo : result){
            Drawable icon = nfo.loadIcon(pm);
            String name = nfo.loadLabel(pm).toString();
            if(name != null && icon != null){
                apps.add(new App(name, icon));
            }
        }
        dialog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
      dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Apps.this,
                "Retreiving Application list",
                "Retrieving list of installed applications", true);

    }

}
```

try the above class , i moved the dialog creation in the onPreExecute method which runs on UI thread

Remember onPreExecute , onPostExecute and onProgressUpdate methods run on UI thread
doInBackground method runs on non-UI thread

Answer (score 1):

Your dialog creation is suppose to be on the UI thread so that I can post back progress to the dialog, implement `onPreExecute()` with your dialog creation code. To post progress call and implement `onProgressUpdate (Progress... values)`.

Answer (score 1):

Move this:

```
dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Apps.this,
        "Retreiving Application list",
        "Retrieving list of installed applications", true);
```

To the onPreExecute method.

onPreExecute (and onPostExecute, where you will cancel the dialog) happens on the UI thread and therefore can make UI changes.
doOnBackground works in a different thread and therefore can't make UI changes.